How do I make the tag info box go away on mobile without refreshing the page?
Sometimes when scrolling on my phone, I tap a tag and the info box appears:

Once it appears, I can’t get it to go away without refreshing the page. This is supremely annoying. How do I make it go away without navigating away or refreshing the page?
I’m using iOS Safari.

For me, it is sufficient to just tap any other part of the screen, outside the info box. To avoid triggering some other feature, I can do so in empty space or on normal, unlinked text. (This is also iOS Safari)

This only works sometimes, so I’m trying to reliably reproduce the behavior where it doesn’t.

@ThomasMarkov I experimented some more: the tag only doesn't vanish if you first tap it to open a new page, then use the back button. In those cases it seems reload is the only thing that helps I could find, at least it keeps you at the same spot
